# resizing a google map to fit a group of markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the V3 version of google maps, and wondered how to go about this-- I have an array of `google.maps.Markers` with their `LatLng` positions set.

I would like to loop through the array and find the min/max latitude and longitude values of the markers, and center and resize the map so all the markers fit on the screen, with a small fudge factor.

Looping through the markers array I can handle, but I'm not sure of how go about centering and resizing the map to fit them all (with a small border region surrounding, so no markers are flush against an edge.)

I'm not sure if this helps or matters but the `<div>` the map lives in is 320x200 pixels.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a function like

```
function setBounds() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i=0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(markersArray[i].getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

As simple as that!

Answer (score 5):

See [the google.maps.Map fitBounds method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Add all the positions of your markers to an empty [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object, then call fitBounds on it.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i=0; i < yourArrayOfMarkers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(yourArrayOfMarkers[i].getPosition();
}
yourMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```